# Execution Plan Time is always 1 ms

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

I try to run an executin plan like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET timed_statistics = TRUE;
set autotrace on explain;
SELECT ename, dname 
FROM emp e, dept d 
WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno 
AND e.hiredate > TO_DATE('29-JUN-1996','DD-MON-YYYY');
set autotrace off;
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                  |    14 |   420 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |                  |    14 |   420 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPT             |     4 |    52 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | DEPT_PRIMARY_KEY |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |                  |    14 |   238 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EMP              |    14 |   238 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("E"."DEPTNO"="D"."DEPTNO")
       filter("E"."DEPTNO"="D"."DEPTNO")
   5 - filter("E"."HIREDATE">TO_DATE(' 1996-06-29 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

As you can see the time is always 1 ms!

What i have made wrong? do i have to set a variable true?

Comment: Your dataset is too tiny (14 rows!). Add a few million rows, analyze both tables and you should get meaningful estimates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually showing a time of 1 second, not 1 millisecond.

The reason it's showing 1 second, is that your dataset is miniscule.  Try adding more data, if you want to think about realistic timing estimates.  With the tiny amount of data you have, 1 second is probably way too high.  In reality, you probably would see a response time closer to 1 ms.  (Your example only has 14 rows in EMP.)

Hope that helps.